# wordninja does not work with other languages

Tags: python, nlp, spelling

I have a question that I cant solve alone. I am currently building an NLP preprocessing pipeline and though about using [wordninja](https://github.com/keredson/wordninja) with cyrilic languages (Russian and Ukrainian) I have set the dictionaries as described and everything seemed to look alright, but I can make it work.

```
import wordninja
wordninja.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_MODEL = wordninja.LanguageModel('setup/ru_ninja_dict.txt.gz')
wordninja.split("приветпока")
```

(the output is an empty list [], while ["привет", "пока"] was expected)

My main assumption is that there is an issue with encodings. However, I do not know how to check it myself.

Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So, as I've figured out, there was an issue in compiling the regex pattern. In the original [wordninja code](https://github.com/keredson/wordninja/blob/master/wordninja.py) there is

```
_SPLIT_RE = re.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+")
```

which will only work with a limited number of languages. (definitely not Cyrillic)

replace with

```
_SPLIT_RE = re.compile("[U+0400–U+04FF]+")
```

for it to work appropriately with Russian, Ukrainian and other slavic languages.